# Choices for ArgParse.jl argument

Tags: julia, argparse.jl

In Python one can set the choices for a flag with `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument('-q', 
                    dest='quality_scale', 
                    type=str, 
                    choices=["sanger", "illumina"],
                    help='Base quality scale',
                    required=True)
```

Is there a way to do this in Julia using `ArgParse`? I checked the documentation [here](https://argparsejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/argparse.html) (General settings), but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `range_tester` parameter, which takes a one-argument function, to perform validation on the input value. Something like the following, which will only accept `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"`.

```
s = ArgParseSettings()
@add_arg_table s begin
    "--opt"
        range_tester = in(["a", "b", "c"])
end
```